# page_size parameter doesn't work for kloudless service

Tags: page-size, kloudless

I'm trying to fetch folder's content from Dropbox through kloudless (https://developers.kloudless.com/docs/v1/storage#folders-retrieve-folder-metadata). I write next query:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' \ 'https://api.kloudless.com/v1/accounts/.../storage/folders/...=/contents?page_size=100'
```

but receive the collection of 600 elements instead of 100. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong. As mentioned in the documentation, the `page_size` parameter is advisory. As such, certain services (like Dropbox) do not currently take that parameter into account and may return a different number of objects than is specified.